# Why do certain individuals struggle to memorize song lyrics?

Tags: neuroscience, learning, psychology, long-term-memory

Some people have a hard time memorizing song lyrics, even after repeated listening.

What individual factors contribute to the difficulty in remembering song lyrics?

Comment: I don't know the reason why, but I am a person who falls in that category.  If you would like to ask me a specific question, I am happy to answer.  I do think part of the reason is that I tend to focus on the melodies instead of the words.  But I'm not sure if that's the chicken or the egg, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are [different kinds of memorizing mechanisms](https://www.verywellmind.com/different-types-of-memory-and-their-functions-5194859), such as  visual, aural, short term, long term, etc.

Most people have an average memory (which may mean high visual memory and low aural memory or vice versa or average both visual and aural memory).

Also they may be more interested in the melody to the lyrics and they just do not pay attention to the lyrics.

It can be a combination of both.

Comment: References would really help this answer.  I doubt that audio (echoic) memory has anything to do with memorizing lyrics - more likely verbal memory.

Comment: It is done I dont have many references because I am interested in the subject  have talked about it with a psychologist so I need to search the internet.Also verbal memory is a subset of aural memory.

Answer (score 0):

Music is a specific form of memory assistance called a mnemonic device. For some it creates connections. Those connections may not be articulable but the brain finds them.

How often one hears a song, the context, and any emotional attachments to the meaning can affect how well lyrics are retained. Active listening takes practice as does memorization, doing both at once with unfamiliar material is an understandable challenge.

The inability to recall this way means that your brain is relying on different connections. For more visual people reading the lyrics or creating a mental image may make them “stick” better than just listening.

The consolation is usually such that when your mental functionality appears lacking in one area it is stronger in another to compensate.

https://lesley.edu/article/stages-of-memory